# How do I make a counter work when you click a button?

Tags: swift, uibutton, int, label

So I'm new to coding and I want to make a label change its text whenever you click the same button. Do this is though you can use variable tied a inter get out and if statements, however did hid not work. Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any)
{
    var nextText:Int = 1
    nextText += 1

    if nextText == 2
    {
        labelOne.text = "We have a developing situation."
    }

    if nextText == 3
    {
        labelOne.text = "About forty five minutes ago 15 unknown assailant broke into Chicago 1st State Bank"
    }

    if nextText == 4
    {
        labelOne.text = "They are armed and dangerous and have taken numerous hostages"
    }

    if nextText == 5
    {
        labelOne.text = "Your mission is to take you and your partner in to bank and free the hostages"
    }

    if nextText == 5
    {
        labelOne.text = "You shall enter the bank via helicopter and rappel onto the roof, good luck."
    }
}
```

Comment: Declear `nextText` as a class level property

Answer (score 0):

Declare your nextText out of the button tap function scope

```
var nextText:Int = 1
@IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any)
{

    nextText += 1

    switch nextText{
     case 2 : labelOne.text = "We have a developing situation."
     case 3 : labelOne.text = "About forty five minutes ago 15 unknown assailant broke into Chicago 1st State Bank"
     case 4 : labelOne.text = "They are armed and dangerous and have taken numerous hostages"
     case 5 : labelOne.text = "Your mission is to take you and your partner in to bank and free the hostages"
     case 6 : labelOne.text = "You shall enter the bank via helicopter and rappel onto the roof, good luck."
     default : labelOne.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this one,

```
var nextText = 0
var labelText = ""

@IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any) {

 switch nextText{
  case 0 : labelText = "We have a developing situation."
  case 1 : labelText = "About forty five minutes ago 15 unknown assailant broke into Chicago 1st State Bank"
  case 2 : labelText = "They are armed and dangerous and have taken numerous hostages"
  case 3 : labelText = "Your mission is to take you and your partner in to bank and free the hostages"
  case 4 : labelText = "You shall enter the bank via helicopter and rappel onto the roof, good luck."
  default : labelText = ""
 }

labelOne.text = labelText
nextText += 1  

}
```